# Error using pytest for my testing, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to Python and testing, I have a huge problem with my Python testing.

So in a folder, I have two other folders one which contains the main code and the other one is the test. I am using VScode

So I have created an environment for testing and everything is fine but the test does not work and it gives me an error

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
___________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_calculate.py ___________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/starm1x/Desktop/Year 3/tests/test_calculate.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../anaconda3/envs/groupProject/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_calculate.py:1: in <module>
    from files.cal import calculate
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'files'
------------------------------- Captured stderr --------------------------------
PYTEST ERROR: TEST_UUID and/or TEST_PORT are not set at the time of pytest starting. Please confirm these environment variables are not being changed or removed as they are required for successful test discovery and execution. 
TEST_UUID = 0a891c40-856f-48f0-9b57-c048ec8bafd1
TEST_PORT = 49472

=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR tests/test_calculate.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
===================== no tests collected, 1 error in 0.04s =====================
<<<PYTHON-EXEC-OUTPUT
```

However, if I am going to have them in the same folder they are working, so I am not getting what is going on.

Please help me,

Thank you

The file structure I have

```
--model
  |    |__one(folder)
  |    |         |___cal.py
  |    |         |___time.py
  |    |__two(folder)
  |              |__mul.py
  |              |__add.py
  |
  |
--test
     |__folderonetest
                |__test_cal.py
     |__foldertwotest
                |__test_mul.py
```

I was trying to use pytest --collect-only did not work

Comment: Please provide the `tree` of your project.

Comment: I update it you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding empty files called `__init__.py`, and rerun from the root. Your tree should look like this:

```
--model
  |    |__one(folder)
  |    |         |___cal.py
  |    |         |___time.py
  |    |         |___ __init__.py
  |    |__two(folder)
  |    |         |__mul.py
  |    |         |__add.py
  |    |         |__ __init__.py
  |    |
  |    |__ __init__.py
--test
     |__folderonetest
                |__test_cal.py
                |__ __init__.py
     |__foldertwotest
                |__test_mul.py
                |__ __init__.py
     |__ __init__.py
```

Comment: Is there another way around it I have tried it works but I will need in future to add it to every single folder __init__.py

Comment: That's the point of using `init` files: you make every subfolder a package. This _is_ the solution, my friend.

Comment: oh thank you so much I was thinking if there is another way of doing, thank you so much

Answer (score -6):

Try adding C:/ before the path like this: 'C:/Users/petrobytsa/Desktop/Year 3/tests/test_calculate.py'.